# Font Awesome Icon Alignment

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm trying to get my home button in the header within a `div` but it is aligning under the `div`/header.

I have this code:

```css
.home-button {
  background: #333;
  width: 59px;
  height: 60px;
  float: right;
  line-height: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
div.home-button i.fa {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="home-button">
  <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

but it is displaying with the icon below the `div`...

Any advice?

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle of your error so we can see it?

Comment: please provide a fiddle or atleast a screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you need to change your `line-height` to `60px`( same value has your `height`) if you want it vertically aligned
- don't need to set other rules to `i`, because `font-awesome.css`already handles that

```css
.home-button {
  background: #333;
  width: 59px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height:60px;
  float:right;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="home-button">
  <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have set your line-height `180px`. Text is than vertically aligned to this value instead of set height of `60px`

```css
.home-button {
  margin-top: 50px;
  background: #333;
  width: 59px;
  height: 60px;
  float: right;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
div.home-button i.fa {
  color: #ddd;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="home-button">
  <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `line-height` from `.home-button` and add it to `i` tag like this:

```css
.home-button {
  background: #333;
  width: 59px;
  height: 60px;
  float: right;  
  text-align: center;  
}
.home-button i {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 60px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="home-button">
  <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```